# Are lambda faster than linq queries?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, parallel-processing, parallel-extensions

Iam playing with lambda, linq and parallel and one question arrives.

Is lambda faster than linq queries?

O write some test code ([Fork it in GitHub](https://github.com/Ewerton/LinqAndLambdaPerformanceTest/blob/master/Program.cs)) and the lambda method seems faster. It is true or i am missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your queries aren't the same.

Query expression:

```
from p in lista 
where p.Age > 18 && p.Age < 60 && p.Phone.StartsWith("11")
select p
```

Regular extension method calls:

```
.Where(n => n.Age > 18).
 Where(n => n.Age < 60).
 Where(n => n.Phone.StartsWith("11"))
```

The first one calls `Where` *once*; the second calls `Where` three times. To make them behave *exactly the same* you should use:

```
.Where(n => n.Age > 18 && n.Age < 60 && n.Phone.StartsWith("11"))
```

At that point, the two forms will compile to exactly the same code.

Additionally, there's a *huge* hole in your testing: you're testing *building* the query... you're never actually *evaluating* it:

```
sw.Start();
IEnumerable listaSemParalelismoLinq = from p in lista
                                      where p.Age > 18 && p.Age < 60 && 
                                            p.Phone.StartsWith("11")
                                      select p;
sw.Stop();
```

You *must* use the query in some form, e.g. calling `Count()` on it, in order to make it actually "execute". (You'll need to change the type to the generic `IEnumerable` form, e.g. using `var`.) The time taken to simply construct the query is basically irrelevant in almost all cases.

Comment: right, i missed this point. Changing the code to test it again.

Answer (score 0):

I do the modifications sugested by @Jon Skeet, run the program in the following order

```
Console.WriteLine("1 - LINQ without paralelism " + LinqWithoutParalelism(lista));
Console.WriteLine("2 - LINQ with paralelism " + LinqWithParalelism(lista));
Console.WriteLine("3 - Lambda without paralelism: " + LambdaWithoutParalelism(lista));
Console.WriteLine("4 - Lambda with paralelism: " + LambdaWithParalelism(lista));
```

And aparently the lamba is faster, but i change the order of the execution to

```
Console.WriteLine("3 - Lambda without paralelism: " + LambdaWithoutParalelism(lista));
Console.WriteLine("4 - Lambda with paralelism: " + LambdaWithParalelism(lista));
Console.WriteLine("1 - LINQ without paralelism " + LinqWithoutParalelism(lista));
Console.WriteLine("2 - LINQ with paralelism " + LinqWithParalelism(lista));
```

and the lambda is not the faster one.
I know this test is very simple and i am not considering the warmup time and to do a lot of interactions, but, ACTUALY my answer is: NO, lambda arent faster than linq queries.

Comment: No, as I said before: the two forms will compile to exactly the same code. Query expressions are effectively transformed by the compiler into "C# without query expressions".

Comment: Do not run several tests in the same execution line, many things can happen... GC could get in the way and so on... Run only 1 test at time and run it several times to get a value you can trust.